# Using macros to include `stddef.h` from GCC version directory

Tags: c, macros, include

I'm trying to include `stddef.h` from GCC folder according to the system version. Using the next sequence of macros:

```
#define __gcc_header(x) #x
#define _gcc_header(x) __gcc_header(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/#x/include/stddef.h)
#define gcc_header(x) _gcc_header(x)
#include gcc_header(__GNUC__)
```

I got the next error:

```
fatal error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/\"11\"/include/stddef.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include gcc_header(__GNUC__)
      |                             ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Why? What problem is that supposed to solve? AT the moment this is very much an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please ask about your original and underlying problem directly instead.

Comment: Remove the `#` in `__gcc_header(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/#x/include/stddef.h)`.

Comment: Assuming you are attempting write portable code, and assign appropriate resources,  you will need to determine if a resource is on your target machine before attempting to define a macro that requires it.  To do things like this,  I have typically seen a series of `#ifdef <some_define_value > __gcc_header(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/x/include/stddef.h)` precompile directives.  ([examples](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/directives/ifdef.php))

Comment: ... another example:  `#if __GNUC__ > 3 || \
    (__GNUC__ == 3 && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 2 || \
                       (__GNUC_MINOR__ == 2 && \
                        __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ > 0))`  ([from here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html))

Comment: Note that all symbols starting with double underscore are [*reserved*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers). Don't create such symbols yourself in your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil), the solution is to use the macros like:

```
#define __gcc_header(x) #x
#define _gcc_header(x) __gcc_header(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/x/include/stddef.h)
#define gcc_header(x) _gcc_header(x)
#include gcc_header(__GNUC__)
```